How to select an input field in ember js via chrome console
Currently there is an input field that displays a search drop down as soon as I click on it , but If I store the field as a global variable and try temp1.select() in chrome console ( temp1 is the name of the global variable) it does not work
However this works when the tab is in the background(not the current tab I am viewing), when I go to the current tab the drop down is already open
after temp1.select() If I click somewhere else on the screen except on the input field it simultaneously opens and closes the search drop down
This could be due to the event stored in a stack but not flushed , But I am note sure how to force the flush of the events
Is there any function that could do this ?
this is the html code
<input aria-label="Search Test" autocomplete="off" 
placeholder="Search Test" id="ember1168" class="ember-text-field 
input--text composable-select__input ember-view" type="text">


After trying out multiple commands I think this works for me, I think we have to focus and then click
$(element).focus().trigger('click');

element could be selected using Xpath here.
In my case it was
$(document.querySelectorAll("*[placeholder=\"Search test\"]")[0]).focus().trigger('click');


We can also use JavaScript event dispatcher as well                                                              var focusEvent = new Event('focus', {   bubbles: true,   cancelable: true, });  element.dispatchEvent(focusevent)

this is going to be app-dependent, but you'd probably need to disable the click-outside behavior of the select to prevent it from closing.

Thanks for the answer, but I do want it to close If I click outside, I want to open the dropdown by giving a command in the dev tools ,  Currently all the events are fired only after I give the click , I am working on a web scraper so changing the code is not an option

ah well, for a scraper, the events you need to emit, and control, and focus you may need to maintain or totally application dependent -- depends on how the site is coded.
